# Matplotlib draw relative points in 3d space

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I would like to draw the trayectories of an industrial robot plotting lines in 3D. I have already something in mind but I am stuck because I want to plot points relative to different frames. I tried something but it is not very elegant. Sorry for not showing it here the source code, technical problems.
I will use matplotlib and Python to program it.
Question: Is there a function in matplotlib to draw relative points in 3D space?

Comment: People need  the "something" you tried but it is not very elegant. Provide example for people here to help you.

Comment: You can see most of what is available in the [tutorials](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), and you can probably make a class to keep track of what those points are relative to and provide the correct coordinates to the plot function.

Answer (score 1):

Relative to what?
It is YOU who can best tell the coordinates of the point.
If you want to count everything relative to a p0(x0,y0) point, then you add the x0, y0 values to each point.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl

points = [[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]]
p0 = [3,3]

for p in points:
    pl.plot(p[0]+p0[0], p[1]+p0[1], "r.")
    print p[0]+p0[0], p[1]+p0[1]
pl.show()
```

If you use numpy then you can even add the p0 to a whole array storing the coordinates.

If you want to calculate each point relative to the previous one, then do so, just little change in the code.